# No products returned from SKProductsRequest

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

This is my first attempt at this and am falling at the get a list of products hurdle!

I have created a ad-hoc profile like: com.mycompany.myproduct and a additional feature on iTunes connect like com.mycompany.myproduct.feature.

The feature is linked to an existing app already on the store but not yet live with in app purchase that uses com.mycompany.myprod as its identifier.

I have build the new version using com.mycompany.myproduct and deployed to my phone and it works ok, apart from when I try to retrieve the list of products available (there is one setup on iTunes connect) I get a return count of 0

Am not sure where I am going wrong so would really appreciate some advice....

Thanks

Comment: I now get invalid product ids which is kind of an improvement.  Dont get what the problem is I have logged out as me on device but do not get prompted to login as my test account?  I have approved the feature but not submitted for review as surely I dont need to whilst testing?  This is rather vague in how to get this to work???

Comment: typo in the provisioning profile was the culprit!

Comment: have you got the answer for this? I am facing exactly the same scenario..

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd help clarify anyone else with this problem finding this through Google.

Check the invalidProductIdentifiers property of your SKProductsResponse object.  It should be empty.

Part of what could be happening is that your identifiers aren't properly configured in iTunesConnect.  They should be listed as "Ready to Submit" or "Waiting for Screenshot"

Comment: +1 good question, good answer. My problem is with a Newstand app. The free subscriptions has data, the payed ones are in invalidProductIdentifyers :)

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, SKProductsRequest don't return products, and check everything according follow [article's suggestion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html), and still don't return products.
Later I reset my iPod, set WiFi, and run again from XCode, it returned product list.

I am quite sure it was resetting iPod, fixed the problem.

Comment: In addition, you may want to delete your app from the device and try it again.