# In App purchase not work on device

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I try to make in app purchase on my app. But I have not result when I try to run it in device.

My code is following:

This is object needed for get info about products and purchase it.

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"

#define kProductsLoadedNotification         @"ProductsLoaded"
#define kProductPurchasedNotification       @"ProductPurchased"
#define kProductPurchaseFailedNotification  @"ProductPurchaseFailed"

@interface StoreManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet * _purchasedProducts;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *products;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSSet *_productIdentifiers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request;

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers;
- (void)requestProducts;
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product;

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "StoreManager.h"

@implementation StoreManager
@synthesize _purchasedProducts;
@synthesize products;
@synthesize _productIdentifiers;
@synthesize request;

// Initializes the request object with the set of product identifiers.
- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self._productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;        
        NSMutableSet *purchased = [NSMutableSet set];
        for(NSString * productId in self._productIdentifiers){
            BOOL flag = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productId];
            if(flag){
                [purchased addObject:productId];
                NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productId);
            }
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productId);
        }
        self._purchasedProducts = purchased;
    }
    return self;
}

// Request info for the product.
- (void)requestProducts{
    self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:self._productIdentifiers];
    self.request.delegate = self;
    [self.request start];
}

// Request fail.
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Fail request! Error: %@", error);
}

// Delegate method - did receive responce.
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:self.products];
}

// Buy product.
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product{    
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

// Payment transactions
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {    
    // TODO: Record the transaction on the server side...    
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");
}

- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    NSLog(@"Toggling flag for: %@", productIdentifier);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self._purchasedProducts addObject:productIdentifier];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier];

}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductPurchaseFailedNotification object:transaction];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}

@end
```

Singleton object

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StoreManager.h"

@interface StoreWrapper : StoreManager

+ (StoreWrapper *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "StoreWrapper.h"

@implementation StoreWrapper
static StoreWrapper *gInstance = NULL;

- (id)init{    
    NSSet *productId = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.company.sb.pack1", @"com.company.sb.pack5", nil];
    self = [super initWithProductIdentifiers:productId];
    if(self){

    }
    return self;
}

+ (StoreWrapper *)sharedInstance{
    if(gInstance == NULL){
        gInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return gInstance;
}

@end
```

In the my view controller i call next:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productsLoaded:) name:kProductsLoadedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:kProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(productPurchaseFailed:) name:kProductPurchaseFailedNotification object: nil];    
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
        NSLog(@"No internet connection!");        
    } else {        
        NSLog(@"Internet connection available!");   
        // Request product
        [[StoreWrapper sharedInstance] requestProducts];        
        [activIndicator startAnimating];
    }    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

for this point I send an request for get product info from server with my product id

next if product loaded my class get notification about this (and call following method).

```
- (void)productsLoaded:(NSNotification *)notification{    
    [activIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activIndicator setHidden:YES];    
    NSArray *arr = [notification object];    
    for(int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++){
        SKProduct *product = [[StoreWrapper sharedInstance].products objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*55, 100, 50)];
        [btn setTitle:product.localizedTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTag:i];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buyProduct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];        
    }    
}
```

For the button i add selector buyProduct (as shown above)

```
- (void)buyProduct:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"sender tag %d", [sender tag]);
    int tag = [sender tag];
    SKProduct *product = [[StoreWrapper sharedInstance].products objectAtIndex:tag];    
    [[StoreWrapper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];    
}
```

For iPhone Simulator this work wonderful, but on device I don have any button, because response.products not download.

All method are called, but delegate method ***- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response*** not return response.products.

Thanks for your time and thanks for answer!

Comment: It works on a simulator? InApp purchase should always be tested on a device. And even there you should log out of your iTunes account and use a test account (specially made for testing in AppStore) within the application.

Comment: yes this is right, but for this time I need to create button only after I get response from server and I have products. If I get products i sent notification with this object and when message a received I create button with a count response products. This is test example only. But it work on simulator only.

Comment: I want to say that depending on the device or simulator - the delegate method - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse )response or return products or not return. This is my problem.

Comment: If you just added the products to the store then maybe everything is not yet 'settled' and could be a server-side problem. I havent done any in-app purchase testing for a few month, maybe something changed. Similiar question poped up few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158778/in-app-purchase-not-work/9159405#9159405  And also today there is some maintanence going on there - it just might not be a problem with your code

Comment: In simulator I have best result. i have ability get products on simulator and all work grateful. but I don't know what happens on device.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563495/no-products-returned-from-skproductsrequest

Comment: thanks for link - this help me. I make hard reset device and all features available now.

Comment: No problem - glad it works! You should mark this question closed. For example add your answer and accept it. Or maybe someone with appropriate privileges should mark it as a duplicate and close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For resolving, this problem I reset my device and rerun the application.

This helps for me.

Comment: After hard reset the delegate method productsRequest working correctly.

Comment: after long searching non of solutions work , but this works fine ..Thanks alot

Comment: How to "reset the delegate method productsRequest"?

Comment: I just done't understand the meaning of "reset" in your "reset the delegate method productsRequest ". Does it mean to restart your app or something like that?