# SKProductsRequest returning 0 Products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to do IAP however for some reason, my SKProductsRequest returns 0 products.

-Test products have been added to iTunes connect properly

-Banking and Taxing information is filled

-The product's bundle id matches the app bundle id

-I've waited up to two days for it to get processed through the servers

I used this youtube tutorial to build the app:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRrs7O5yjKI

And here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblAd: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCoinAmount: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var outRemoveAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var outAddCoins: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var outRestorePurchases: UIButton!



    var coins = 50

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        outRemoveAds.isEnabled = false
        outAddCoins.isEnabled = false
        outRestorePurchases.isEnabled = false

        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            print("IAP is enabled, loading")
            let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.IAPTesters.10Dolla", "com.IAPTesters.RemoveAds")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func btnRemoveAds(_ sender: Any) {
        print("rem ads")
        for product in list {
            let prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "com.IAPTesters.RemoveAds") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnAddCoins(_ sender: Any) {
        for product in list {
            let prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "com.IAPTesters.10Dolla") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnRestorePurchases(_ sender: Any) {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    func buyProduct() {
        print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
        let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func removeAds() {
        lblAd.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func addCoins() {
        coins += 50
        lblCoinAmount.text = "\(coins)"
    }

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("product request")
        let myProduct = response.products
        for product in myProduct {
            print("product added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)

            list.append(product)
        }

        outRemoveAds.isEnabled = true
        outAddCoins.isEnabled = true
        outRestorePurchases.isEnabled = true
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("transactions restored")
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "com.IAPTesters.RemoveAds":
                print("remove ads")
                removeAds()
            case "com.IAPTesters.10Dolla":
                print("add coins to account")
                addCoins()
            default:
                print("IAP not found")
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("add payment")

        for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print("buy ok, unlock IAP HERE")
                print(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier
                switch prodID {
                case "com.IAPTesters.RemoveAds":
                    print("remove ads")
                    removeAds()
                case "com.IAPTesters.10Dolla":
                    print("add coins to account")
                    addCoins()
                default:
                    print("IAP not found")
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            case .failed:
                print("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                print("Default")
                break
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

When you run the app it will print "IAP is enabled, loading" and than "product request" but nothing else.

If I print `response.invalidProductIdentifiers` in the productsRequest function it will return my products: `["com.IAPTesters.RemoveAds", "com.IAPTesters.10Dolla"]`

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Read the note in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest); you must retain your product request in a property

Comment: @Paulw11 I still don't understand that kind of changes that need to be made to the code

Comment: Your product request object can't be a local variable as it will be released as soon as the function exits (which is before the request completes). You need to hold your request in a property.

Comment: @Paulw11 are you referring to the variable I called myProduct in the productRequests function or the request variable in viewDidLoad().

Comment: Take a look here as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563495/no-products-returned-from-skproductsrequest?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that my banking and taxing information was filled out incorrectly. I refilled it and than I had to wait about 30 minutes for it to work again. Everything is now working correctly! Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the [`SKProductsRequest` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest) you will see:

> **Note**
>
> Be sure to keep a strong reference to the request object; otherwise, the system might deallocate the request before it can complete.

Your `SKProductsRequest` instance is a local constant in `viewDidLoad`. This will be deallocated as soon as `viewDidLoad` exits and since the product request will complete asynchronously,  this will be before the request is completed and you will therefore never get a call back.

You should retain your `SKProductsRequest` in a property so that it isn't released.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblAd: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCoinAmount: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var outRemoveAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var outAddCoins: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var outRestorePurchases: UIButton!

    var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?

    var coins = 50

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        outRemoveAds.isEnabled = false
        outAddCoins.isEnabled = false
        outRestorePurchases.isEnabled = false

        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            print("IAP is enabled, loading")
            let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.IAPTesters.10Dolla", "com.IAPTesters.RemoveAds")
            self.productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request?.delegate = self
            request?.start()
        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }
    }

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("product request")
        let myProduct = response.products
        for product in myProduct {
            print("product added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)

            list.append(product)
        }

        outRemoveAds.isEnabled = true
        outAddCoins.isEnabled = true
        outRestorePurchases.isEnabled = true

        self.productsRequest = nil
    }
```

FYI, your implementation of `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is incorrect; you should process the restored transactions in `updatedTransactions` through the `.restored` transaction state.  The `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` method should only be used to update your UI or perform any other tasks that are required when the restoration process is complete.

Comment: I tried doing what you showed however, it still didn't print all the products.

Comment: Is your delegate now being called? Did you check the invalid products property of the response?

Comment: my delegate method is being called... it just prints "product request" and if I print myProduct.count in my productsRequest function it still returns 0.

Comment: Check the invalidProducts; chances are your product identifiers are not correct. Are you testing on an actual device and not the simulator?

Comment: Yes im testing it on my phone and on the simulator because in the video whose link i posted, he was able to get the products listed by testing it in the simulator and I'm not getting an invalid product ID error, it just stops printing after "product request"

Comment: It isn’t an invalid product Id error; there is a property of the response that contains the invalid product ids. Every id you send in your request will either be in the valid products or invalid products list.

Comment: when i print the invalid products it prints: ["com.IAPTesters.RemoveAds", "com.IAPTesters.10Dolla"]...what exactly makes them invalid? Because on iTunes their statuses are "Ready to Submit"

Answer (score 0):

If I 'm understood correctly then the problem with your implementation is you have created your products in iTunes with wrong identifiers. As I know the product identifiers should be like your application bundle identifier followed by your product functionality `i.e, COM.COMPANYNAME.MYNEWAPPLICATION.REMOVEADS, COM.COMPANYNAME.MYNEWAPPLICATION.10DOLLA`

Sample code be like,

```
typealias SSIAPHelperCompletion = (_ result: [SKProduct]?, _ error: Error?) ->Void

class SSIAPHelper: NSObject {
    fileprivate let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(arrayLiteral: "com.companyname.appname.removeads","com.companyname.appname.10dolla"))

    fileprivate var completion: SSIAPHelperCompletion?

    static let shared = SSIAPHelper()

    func requestProducts(completionHandler: @escaping SSIAPHelperCompletion) {
        self.completion = completionHandler
        self.productsRequest.delegate = SSIAPHelper.shared
        self.productsRequest.start()
    }
}

extension SSIAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate{
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        print(#function)
    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print(#function, response.products)
        if let lCompletion = self.completion{
            lCompletion(response.products, nil)
        }
    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

You can get products by simply calling below function from your `viewDidLoad()`

```
SSIAPHelper.shared.requestProducts(completionHandler: { (result, error) in

            })
```

Comment: Product identifiers are not required to have the reverse domain pattern like com.company.app.inapp-product-id.  That is just a recommendation to make them unique and easy to keep track of.  I have inherited apps from clients which have simple names for in-app purchase identifiers.

Comment: @Jayachandra A I've double checked that my products in iTunes connect are created with proper identifiers that match to my application bundle id